# Hyper-V Point to Point using FC HBA

Tags: fibre-channel, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, hba

Is it possible to connect Point to Point two Hyper-V servers using FC HBA to replicate data without connection to external storage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of setup model is called hyper-convergence when compute and storage are running on the same hosts.

From my experience, I have never meet FC HBA that could run replication between 2 directly connected hosts. Check specifics of your FC, could it proceed with [EoFC](https://datacenteroverlords.com/2015/04/01/ethernet-over-fibre-channel/). If so, FC could be used for configuration of iSCSI shared storage between nodes since it encapsulates Ethernet packets into Fibre Channel frame.

Check [HPE VSA](https://www.hpe.com/us/en/storage/software-defined.html), [StarWind Virtual SAN](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free), [S2D](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/storage/storage-spaces/storage-spaces-direct-overview). Those software solutions allow to configure shared storage mirroring between 2 and more hosts typical Ethernet networks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IP-over-FC in theory but keeping in mind 10 GbE is cheap these days I'd a) leave FC to storage, and b) got myself a pair of Mellanox CX4lc to live long and happy life ;)